# variable in sparql

Tags: php, variables, rdf, sparql

This examples are not working for me.

```
$title = "Hamlet";

$q =' http://localhost/arc2-starter-pack/OL24929270M.rdf { http://openlibrary.org/books/OL24929270M http://purl.org/dc/terms/title ' . $title . ' };
```

Comment: Where did this code come from?  This isn't a syntactically correct SPARQL query.  What is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your string, eg.

```
$q =' http://localhost/arc2-starter-pack/OL24929270M.rdf { http://openlibrary.org/books/OL24929270M http://purl.org/dc/terms/title "' . $title . '" }';
```

Otherwise the word Hamlet will appear inside the query as a bareword, which will be a syntax error.

Note however, you should really be escaping $title to be safe.